# How to create a log file in c# for windows application?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

How to create log files in windows application???

Please help me with any example, in which file can be saved on specific path.

Thanks in advance

Comment: _Plz help me with the code_ is not a good way to ask. Did you try _anything_ so far? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] .

Comment: use log4net and take a look at their documentation

Comment: @SonerGönül first of all I don't know what is log file, without knowing anything about that how can you expect me to put an effort as if I don't put your coolly speaking, what do you know about my work and the situation, try to respect people.... if you can... provide the answers otherwise keep your mouth shut.... I taught this is the site where we can get some help.. Don't ever dominate others... don't forget that you were also a beginner in your past

Comment: @JeswinRebil Don't be ridiculous. Every site has rules that you're expected to follow. Don't be offended when you get called out for it. Certainly don't tell others you're exempt from the rules just because you're new. Member for 6 months with no answers, votes, or otherwise useful content. Portrait http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem

Comment: @SonerGönül Also check that,Insults are not welcome,Let's work to help developers, not make thm feel stupid.I didn't say that i m exempt from the rules.Yes i m the member for 6 months,inactive for 5 months and jsut active from 3 weeks before,I just post the questions, I am not genius like you to answer the others.I didn't get the answers because of you guys only, you will overreact if the question was silly and say that this was already there, this is the not a good way to ask and reduce my reputations, Enough of this argument just mind your business, don't show superiority or superciliousness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be doing you a disservice to give you "code for logging", but I can point you towards the `File` class, which contains useful methods for writing text to a file.  Since you specify no other needs,  I suspect it will suffice.

`File`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would evaluate Log4Net, it is an excellent logging tool allow for full customisation of logging level and logging output (file, database, email etc).

[Nuget Log4Net](http://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net/2.0.3)